# Processing web requests in Java desktop application through tor network?

Tags: java, desktop, configure, tor

I write Java desktop applications sometimes and sometimes I would like for my web requests to be processed through the tor network.

How can I go about configuring this properly in Windows and/or Linux?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [netlib librar](https://silvertunnel.org/netlib.html)y to push all your JVM traffic through TOR.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to using Web Service technology. Web Service is independent technology and by it can connect several application with different technology together. For example you can develop server with .Net platform and develop client with Java,Php,Python or others (or vice versa). Web Service in java has JADX-RPC(older) and JAX-WS standards.